# Is this possible? produce 7 bit sum with one full adder?

Tags: adder

i have no idea how to do this all I know is adding 2 bits with one half adder and use bunch of full adder to get a n bit sum...
the original question is below

Design a circuit that adds together 4X and 8X to give 12X, where X is X2X1X0, and gives a 7-­‐bit sum S6S5S4S3S2S1S0. This can be done using 1 full adder and 2 half adders, no additional gates are required.

please help

Comment: It appears that you've simply copy-pasted your homework here.  Please put some effort into your formatting, and explain what you've done and why it doesn't seem right or where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4X can be formed by left-shifting X by two bits, and 8X can be formed by left-shifting by 3 bits. So to get 12X you have

```
    X2 X1 X0  0  0  0
 +     X2 X1 X0  0  0
    =================
 S6 S5 S4 S3 S2 S1 S0
```

Now you can just work out the addition:

```
 S0 = 0
 S1 = 0
 S2 = X0
 S3 = X0 + X1       (and generates a carry bit C0)
 S4 = X1 + X2 + C0  (and generates carry bit C1)  
 S5 = X2 + C1       (and generates carry bit C2)
 S6 = C2
```

That shows that S0, S1, and S2 can be generated by wires, S3 and S5 can be generated half-adders, S4 can be generated by a half-adder, and S6 is just the carry output of the S5 half-adder.